# TYPO3 - One backend layout and one template for multiple pages

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

I'm relatively new to TYPO3. But im sure thats basic stuff what im asking here!

So i have a Page named "Services" with some Subpages like "Service 1, Service 2" etc.

For every Subpage I made its own template and its own backend layout:

```
Service 1 => /Templates/Service_1.html => /BackenLayouts/service_1.tsconfig
Service 2 => /Templates/Service_2.html => /BackenLayouts/service_2.tsconfig
```

I need a template for every backend layout, otherwise Ii get an error that TYPO3 doesn't find the right template in the template folder.

But that feels like it's not really the right way to do it and it's really time consuming.

How can I use the same template for multiple pages, because the only things changing is the content but not the structure/design.

I hope someone can assist me here or put me in the right direction.

Comment: A basic installation of TYPO3 is blank and does not have any information about the templates to be used... So it would be helpful to know more about your project. You (or some extension) have configured how the page/frontend should look like. This configuration is the key you are looking for.